# Is there any sport that helps increase height?

Tags: weight-loss, strength, muscle, injury, sports

im 13 and i want to be taller is ther any sports can help to increase height cause im Short compared to the same age hope find a sport

Comment: You are 13. It is very unlikely you have stopped growing. Give it time.

Answer (score 1):

No.

No sport can increase your height. Your maximal physical height is limited by your skeleton.

Comment: Absent any disease or other metabolic condition, of course.